# How to make an NumericUpDown on the Iphone?

Tags: iphone, numericupdown

I am trying to firgure out a way to make an NumericUpDown component for the Iphone. Anyone know if something like that already exists ?

Any idea what would be a good approach to create something like that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If your NumericUpDown mean images in this [google search](http://www.google.com.vn/images?q=numericupdown&um=1&ie=UTF-8&source=og&sa=N&hl=vi&tab=wi&biw=1280&bih=632) then I can suggest you go with iphone UIPickerView or [this one](http://www.roseindia.net/tutorial/iphone/examples/UIPickerView/UIPickerViewExample.html)

Comment: Yes, this is precisely what the `UIPickerView` was designed for. Please *do not* make me try to "click" those tiny little up/down buttons with my finger. I'd +1 if I wasn't out of votes.

Comment: Well, the google search is exactly what I want to achieve, BUT I am also totally aware that it needs to be work with normal fingertips. The problem with UIPickerView would be that I need to know upfront the possible values.... not really working for a couple of thousand values.

Comment: I think you may just do like a way a UITableView does: when user is in the end of the table view, load more and set the data source again